# Exercise 6, Section 47 of Munkres’ Elements of Algebraic Topology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I've been reading through the section on cohomology of Munkres' elements of algebraic topology book and I'm having some problems trying to solve one exercise (Exercise 6 of section 47).

> The exercise asks to compute the cohomology of the 5-fold dunce cap $X$ (which is defined as a pentagon with all its sides identified) with $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z/5$ coefficients, and then triangulate $X$ to find cocycles that generate the cohomology.

I'm able to compute the cohomology calculating first the homology and then using the universal coefficient theorem. I got that $H^0(X,\mathbb Z)=\mathbb Z$, $H^2(X,\mathbb Z)=\mathbb Z/5$, and zero otherwise, and also that $H^n(X,\mathbb Z/5)$ is nonzero only if $n=0,1,2$, in which case equals $\mathbb Z/5$.

However, I don't know how to proceed to find the cocyles that generate these groups. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: just complete sidenote: if you can find a different text, then i recommend it. this book is okay because it's very combinatorial but the perspective is definitely a bit weird imo

Answer (score 1):

Use the most obvious triangulation. [image]

I have left edges unlabelled for legibility; there are two vertices, $v$ and the central $w$, five faces $\sigma_\bullet$ and five unmarked edges which run $v\to w$, where $e_1$ is thought to be the base (the "$d_2$" face) of $\sigma_1$, etc. and a sixth unmarked edge $e_0$ which is the identified edge as per the green arrows. This is the "$d_1$" face of every one of the $\sigma_\bullet$; I chose them oriented in this manner.

Remember this is all a code for: take those simplices (maps $\Delta^k\to Y$) and compose them with the quotient map $Y\twoheadrightarrow X$ down to the dunce cap.

This surely triangulates and allows a very easy computation of both cohomology and generating simplicial cocycles. Identifying $\hom(\Bbb Z,\Bbb Z)\cong\Bbb Z$ in the most canonical way; $\phi\sim\phi(1)$; we see the cochain complex is identifiable with: $$0\to\Bbb Z^2\overset{\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\-1&1\\-1&1\\-1&1\\-1&1\\-1&1\end{pmatrix}}{\longrightarrow}\Bbb Z^6\overset{\begin{pmatrix}-1&1&-1&0&0&0\\-1&0&1&-1&0&0\\-1&0&0&1&-1&0\\-1&0&0&0&1&-1\\-1&-1&0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}}{\longrightarrow}\Bbb Z^5\to0$$

Where I took the ordered bases $\{v,w\}$ and $\{e_0,e_1,\cdots,e_5\}$ and $\{\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\cdots,\sigma_5\}$. It is elementary to check $H^0\cong\Bbb Z$ as generated by, say, the cocycle $\phi:v\mapsto1,w\mapsto1$ and it is easy to check $H^1=0$ here.

The trace map $\Bbb Z^5\to\Bbb Z/5,(a,b,c,d,e)\mapsto[a+b+c+d+e]$ identifies $H^2\cong\Bbb Z/5$. Any choice with nonzero trace gives a generator. For example, the $2$-cocyle $\phi:\sigma_1\mapsto1,\,\sigma_{i>1}\mapsto0$ generates the second simplicial cohomology group.

Finding a generator of $H^1(X;\Bbb Z/5)$ is a bit more interesting. The map $\ker\to\Bbb Z/5,(a,b,c,d,e,f)\mapsto[b-c]$ witnesses the isomorphism; well, the kernel of this is all the coboundaries, so we just have to check it surjects which boils down to finding $(a,b,c,d,e,f)$ such that $1=a=b-c=c-d=d-e=e-f=f-b$ in $\Bbb Z/5$. Let's be simple. Try $b=1,c=0$. Then $d=-1,e=-2,f=-3$ and it works since $-3-1=1$ modulo $5$. That is: $$\phi:\begin{pmatrix}e_0\\e_1\\e_2\\e_3\\e_4\\e_5\end{pmatrix}\mapsto\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\\-1\\3\\2\end{pmatrix}$$Is a $1$-cocycle which generates $H^1(X;\Bbb Z/5)$.

Really this is just a simple linear algebra question.